# Count occurrences across each row in mySQL

Tags: mysql, database

I have been racking my brain on how to count how often a string occurs across each row, and ultimately update another column.

If I have the questions table that contains a sponsors answers for each question in a record:

```
+-------------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| response_id | q1  | q2  | q3  | q4  | q5  |
+-------------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|           1 | Yes | N/A | Yes | No  | Yes |
|           2 | No  | Yes | No  | Yes | N/A |
|           3 | Yes | No  | No  | N/A | Yes |
+-------------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

Is it possible to do this:

```
+-------------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+----+-----+
| response_id | q1  | q2  | q3  | q4  | q5  | Yes | No | N/A |
+-------------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+----+-----+
|           1 | Yes | N/A | Yes | No  | Yes |   2 |  1 |   1 |
|           2 | No  | Yes | No  | Yes | N/A |   2 |  1 |   1 |
|           3 | Yes | No  | No  | N/A | Yes |   1 |  1 |   2 |
+-------------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+----+-----+
```

I am importing this data from an csv to a Laravel application. It if's not possible, is there a way I can rearrange this data to get to the end result.

Thanks!

Comment: I believe that a good solution is to use a mysql stored procedure over the data after the import process be finished.

Comment: Got a stored procedure set up. Thank you for this advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the update query like the one below:

```
update responses set Yes = IF(q1='Yes',1,0) 
        + IF(q2='Yes',1,0)
        + IF(q3='Yes',1,0)
        + IF(q4='Yes',1,0)
        + IF(q5='Yes',1,0);
```

This will update the existing rows (here's **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/db49fd/1/0)**). For the new rows, you can write something in the application itself, to caculate these values before a row is inserted.

Comment: Thank you so much! This works great! You have no idea how much I've spend on this. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Here the hole query for you:

```
SELECT
     response_id
    ,q1,q2,q3,q4,q5
    , IF ( q1 = 'Yes', 1,0)+IF ( q2 = 'Yes', 1,0)+IF ( q3 = 'Yes', 1,0)+IF ( q4 = 'Yes', 1,0)+IF ( q5 = 'Yes', 1,0)  AS `Yes`
    , IF ( q1 = 'No', 1,0)+IF ( q2 = 'No', 1,0)+IF ( q3 = 'No', 1,0)+IF ( q4 = 'No', 1,0)+IF ( q5 = 'No', 1,0)  AS `No`
    , IF ( q1 = 'N/A', 1,0)+IF ( q2 = 'N/A', 1,0)+IF ( q3 = 'N/A', 1,0)+IF ( q4 = 'N/A', 1,0)+IF ( q5 = 'N/A', 1,0)  AS `N/A`
FROM my_table;
```